# How to handle Attribute error when beautifull soup does not find an element

Tags: python, web, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape a real estate website in Lebanon, some properties have a description of their available amenities and some don't.

After storing the links to scrape in a excel column, I iterate over them to access them and extract the available amenities for that property.

But some properties are Lands for example, and those don't have any amenities, so when my code runs into that case, it raises a "Attribute Error".

The code below is with the try and except scheme, but what I want is to set an "no amenities" value in the list where I store my amenities soupObject when there are none.

Any help would be much appreciated,

```
import bs4
import requests


amenity_soupObject=[]
for cellObj in sheet['A']: ##here the A represents the column name
    try:
        link = cellObj.value
        ress = requests.get(link)
        time.sleep(0.2)
        soup_finder = bs4.BeautifulSoup(ress.text) 


        propAmenities=soup_finder.find("div", class_="amenities_container")
        propAmenities1 = bs4.BeautifulSoup(propAmenities.text)
        amenity_soupObject.append(propAmenities1)
        print(propAmenities1)

     except: "AttributeError"
         amenity_soupObject.append("no amenities here")
```

Comment: What's wrong with your code? (Remove colon and quotes around "AttributeError")

Comment: `except: "AttributeError"` looks wrong. Is that the real code? It should be `except AttributeError:`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Camille. Have a look at how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Try `except AttributeError as error:` instead. `propAmenities` is probably `None`, trying printing it after the `find()` call.